# Getting directory list with serial number in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I wanna list out all the sub directory in a main directory with a serial numbers.

Example :

If a directory A contains B,C,D and E as a sub directory then the output should be like

```
1 B
2 C
3 D
4 E
```

Answer (score 3):

**ls | nl ;**
where ls is for listing the directory files and nl is for numbered line

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop:

```
i=0
for f in A/*/; do
    echo "$((++i)) $f"
done
```

The pattern matches all directories in A. `$((++i))` increments the variable `$i` by 1 for each directory that is found.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do with the number. If you plan to use it further/later, and anyone could make or delete directories between looking at the list and using the number, you will be in trouble.

If that is the case, you can use the inode numbers of the directories like this as they are constant and unique across the entire filesystem:

```
ls -di */
19866918 f/ 19803132 other/ 19705681 save/
```

On a Mac, you can also do

```
stat -f '%i %N' */
19866918 f/
19803132 other/
19705681 save/
```

and I believe the Linux equivalent is

```
stat -c '%i %N' */
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
find * -type d | nl
```

`find * -type d` : print name of all directories in current path

`nl` : add line number to output

Comment: I guess that `-maxdepth 1` might also be useful, so that subdirectories are not matched. Also, I think you should remove the `*` entirely as it is currently being expanded by the shell, causing `find` to search for directories within each directory. Perhaps you meant `-name '*'`?